# Using blurred background in view with the storyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

(I am using Swift with iOS 8)

I am adding a (Sub)View to a UiViewController. This subview should hold a few UiLabels with some information in it. I want the subview to have a blurred background like the notification center of iOS has.

I know this is possible using UIEffectView, but how could I assign such a blurred effect using the storyboard? I actually don't want to create my views programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes this is possible in Xcode 6. Just search for "Visual Effect View with Blur" in the object library (bottom right). These can be added to your view controllers like any other view. You can also change the blur style in the attributes inspector (light, dark, extra light).

Hope this helps.