# Make ViewController background Blur

Tags: swift

I got UIViewController contain custom navigationbar and an UITableView
I am trying to make all the view background blur so the icons and lable and information show above blur effect 
I tried this but the blur effect apply on the icons and information

this code in viewWillAppear

```
//Background
ChatRoomTable.backgroundColor = .clear
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "16.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
ChatRoomTable.backgroundView = imageView
ChatRoomTable.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
ChatRoomTable.sectionIndexColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6715271832)
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
view.addSubview(blurView)
```

**Update**

[image: current image]

I want background like this and every thing show above

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the screenshots for how the UI is looking like now and how you want it to be ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355606/using-blurred-background-in-view-with-the-storyboard-in-ios

Comment: @Scriptable done check updated post

Comment: @SemarY go through this [link](https://medium.com/@mohau/blurred-background-semi-transparent-modal-view-swift-3-xcode-tutorial-1f67566bb449) and you achieve what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SemarY I got your bug you added image you at wrong place so let me give you code which will help you for your desire output.

```
//Background
ChatRoomTable.backgroundColor = .clear
ChatRoomTable.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
ChatRoomTable.sectionIndexColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6715271832)
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "16.png")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
imageView.frame = self.view bound
view.addSubView(imageView)
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
view.addSubview(blurView)
self.bringSubviewToFront(ChatRoomTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the image to the `Content View` of the `blurView` like so `blurView.contentView.addSubview(imageView)`